# How to limit soapUI bandwitdh when connecting to a JBoss server on localhost

Tags: web-services, testing, jboss, soapui

I have developed a webservice that I need to test under bad connection speed conditions. The webservice is deployed under JBoss 6.0 and I am using soapUI 4.0.0 for testing.

I need to limit the connection speed of soapUI to about 56kbps (dial-up) so as to make sure I don't get timeouts on requests and the such.

I've done some google-ing but have found nothing satisfactory.

Has anyone had this issue before and found an adequate solution?

Many thanks,

edit1: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Why not test with a PC on a 56 kbps modem?
Or a PC on the network, but limit its connection (somehow - there must be a way) to 56kbps.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to another computer. And because of security issues I can't take the service at home to test on my own server.